# "When would I use which" vs. "When to use which"

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts (["Farthest" vs. "The farthest"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/243177/109190)) I said

> Is there some difference in meaning? When would I use which?

I guess it is grammatical, though it does not seem to be idiomatic, according to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=When+would+I+use+which%2Cwhen+to+use+which%2C+When+should+I+use+each&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwhen%20to%20use%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwhen%20to%20use%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWhen%20to%20Use%20Which%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWhen%20to%20use%20which%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cwhen%20to%20use%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwhen%20to%20use%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWhen%20to%20Use%20Which%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWhen%20to%20use%20which%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

"Ngrams not found: When would I use which, When should I use each" indicate somehow people rarely say it that way.

However, if I had said this way

> Is there some difference in meaning? When to use which?

The second sentence dose not seem grammatical.

What am I missing? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing context. How can be tell you without a sentence at least? Please provide one. And please use a better title such as farthest or the farthest.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely avoid using "When to use which?" This doesn't really make sense as it is missing the auxiliary verb.
"When would I use which?" is good and understandable but still sounds a tiny bit strange.
Best is "When should I use each one?". Using "would" instead of "should" is perfectly fine but "should" is more common for this.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I updated my OP. Google Ngram says "not found" for "When should I use each".

Comment: It might be that it's a personal preference or dialectal thing. To me "When should I use each one" sounds the best. If you or others disagree, you could try rewriting to the sentence. Maybe something like "How do I know which one to use?"

Comment: What I meant is not a disagreement, and it is not an agreement either. I'd just like to know how to choose expressions. I didn't realize it is a matter of preference, that's why I made the first comment. I got it now. Thank you, that's very kind of you. – WXJ96163 14 mins ago   Delete

Comment: "would" conveys a different flavor than "should" to me. "When should I" sounds like a genuine question which is mostly unbiased. "When *would* I" sounds like a question about a situation that the questioner finds unlikely, strange, or surprising. Something like "Hey, whenever you jump over a cow, watch out for their horns!" - "(When/Why) would I jump over a cow?". Whereas the question "*Why should* I jump over a cow" sounds like asking for physiotherapeutical benefits of cow jumping, and "*When should* I..." sounds like asking what the best time for one's daily cow jumping routine is.