# How do I refer to an agreement grammatically?

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts (["When would I use which" vs. "When to use which"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/243191/109190)) I said

> What I meant is not a disagreement, and it is not an agreement either. I'd just like to know how to choose expressions.

Actually, I spent a long time to construct the sentence above. Here are some of my options

> What I meant is neither a disagreement nor an agreement ...
>
> I am not agreeing. I am not disagreeing either ...

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20not%20disagreeing%2Cis%20disagreeing%2C%20is%20a%20disagreement%2C%20is%20disagreement%2C%20&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20not%20disagreeing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20disagreeing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20disagreement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20disagreement%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20not%20disagreeing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20disagreeing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20disagreement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20disagreement%3B%2Cc0) makes things harder.

[image]

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tricky thing: We had a disagreement. OK, we did not agree on something but this: We had an agreement usually refers to something more formal like a gentlemen's agreement or a written document. We'd say here: "We agreed that etc."

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker, I would say something more succinct:

> I’m neither agreeing nor disagreeing

(Or perhaps something worded even more differently, such as “I’m not trying to express an opinion”, “I’m neutral”, etc.)

It might also be relevant to note that “neither agree nor disagree” is commonly found on [surveys as the middle option](https://blogs.worldbank.org/impactevaluations/do-you-agree-or-disagree-how-ask-question).